# When did Udina become Councilor?

Tags: mass-effect-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is Anderson not a councilor?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/55465/why-is-anderson-not-a-councilor)

At the end of Mass Effect (1), I declined to voice an opinion regarding my preference for Human representation on the Council.  At the start of ME2, I was forced to choose.  I picked Anderson.  However, at the start of ME3, Udina has the job and there's no immediate explanation for it.  Also, Anderson seems to be just as deeply involved with the military as if he'd never left his original position.

Is this ever explained in the Trilogy?  Is there an explanation for it outside of the games?

Comment: @agent86 Thanks.  Could you delete this for me, then?  Apparently, since it was closed by a "vote", I have to wait 2 days to do it myself - whereas I would have been able to do it immediately if it weren't closed.

Comment: why delete it? Closed duplicates are a good thing, so long as they aren't word for word dupes. They improve searchability.

Comment: Yeah, this is sort of the opposite phrasing of the dupe question, so it's fine with me if it stays.

Comment: @agent86 Good point, there.  I withdraw my request, then.